# How to process a flat file with JSON string as a part of each line, into CSV file Using PIG Loader?

Tags: csv, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a file in HDFS as

> 44,UK,{"names":{"name1":"John","name2":"marry","name3":"stuart"},"fruits":{"fruit1":"apple","fruit2":"orange"}},31-07-2016
>
> 91,INDIA,{"names":{"name1":"Ram","name2":"Sam"},"fruits":{}},31-07-2016

and want to store this into a SCV file as below using PIG loader :

> 44,UK,names,name1,John,31-07-2016
> 44,UK,names,name2,Marry,31-07-2016
> ..
> 44,UK,fruit,fruit1,apple,31-07-2016
> ..
> 91,INDIA,names,name1,Ram,31-07-2016
> ..
> 91,INDIA,null,null,Ram,31-07-2016

What should be the PIG script for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your record is not a proper JSON string any json storer/loader will not help you. Writing a UDF will be a simpler approach.

UPDATED APPROACH 1 :-

Below UDF and PIG script will work if you are converting your input to tab separated file.

UDF :-

```
package com.test.udf;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
*input format :-
*  {"names":{"name1":"John","name2":"marry","name3":"stuart"},"fruits":    {"fruit1":"apple","fruit2":"orange"}}
*/
public class jsonToTuples extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
};

@Override
public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        String jsonRecord = (String) input.get(0);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(jsonRecord)) {
            try {
                List<String> recordList = new ArrayList<String>();
                Map<String, Object> jsonDataMap = objectMapper.readValue(jsonRecord, typeRef);
                if(jsonDataMap.get("names") != null) {
                    Map<String, String> namesDataMap  = (Map<String, String>) jsonDataMap.get("names");
                    for(String key : namesDataMap.keySet()){
                        recordList.add("names" + "," + key + "," + namesDataMap.get(key));
                    }

                }
                if(jsonDataMap.get("fruits") != null) {
                    Map<String, String> fruitsDataMap  = (Map<String, String>) jsonDataMap.get("fruits");
                    for(String key : fruitsDataMap.keySet()){
                        recordList.add("fruits" + "," + key + "," + fruitsDataMap.get(key));
                    }

                }
                DataBag outputBag = BagFactory.getInstance().newDefaultBag();
                for( int i = 0 ; i < recordList.size() ; i++){
                    Tuple outputTuple = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(1);
                    outputTuple.set(0 , recordList.get(i));
                    outputBag.add(outputTuple);
                }

                return outputBag;
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("caught exception for ");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
    }
}
```

PIG SCRIPT :-

```
register 'testUDF.jar' ;
A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage() as (id:chararray , country:chararray , record:chararray , date:chararray);
B = Foreach A generate id, country , FLATTEN(com.test.udf.jsonToTuples(record)) , date ;
dump B ;
```

OLD APPROACH :-

Below I am mentioning the way I will use in my UDF to read your record if it is comma separated.

As mentined in my below comment try to use magic of split in UDF to separate your fields. I have not tested but here is what I may try in my UDF :-

(please note that I am not sure this is best option - you may want to improve it further.)

```
String[] strSplit = ((String) input.get(0)).split("," , 3);
String id = strSplit[0] ;
String country = strSplit[1] ;
String jsonWithDate = strSplit[2] ;

String[] datePart =  ((String) input.get(0)).split(",");    
String date = datePart[datePart.length-1];

/**
 * above jsonWithDate should look like -
 * {"names":{"name1":"Ram","name2":"Sam"},"fruits":{}},31-07-2016
 * 
*/
String jsonString = jsonWithDate.replace(date,"").replace(",$", "");

/**
* now use some parser or object mapper to convert jsonString to desired list of values.
*/
```

Comment: Hi @sorabh, while i execute the script all data is stored in 1st column i.e id . Rest country ,record and date is empty. So what should be the separator i should mentioned so that record column has JSON data.then only i can go for jsonTuples UDF.

Comment: aah I got your issue. Comma (,) separator will not work for you.Then why not you read whole record string and then do all processing in your UDF ? I will try to modify above answer accordingly.

Comment: @papu.ray I have tried to suggest way to extract fields out of your record in UDF. Please ckeck if it makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks @sorabh, I put '/t' in between fields so i can now pack whole JSON data into one column. So i can go for jsonToTuples UDF option. Is jsonToTuples UDF is inbuilt or custom UDF or i have to include some jar file for this. Please share me jsonToTuples UDF code . Please help me on this i am new to PIG. Thank you.

Comment: @papu.ray I am implemented UDF and updated my answer with same. This should help you.

Comment: @papu.ray are you able to use the UDF ?

Comment: I will let you know if i will face any other technical issue. Thanks a lot.