# Cannot load full data in the JSON using JsonLoader

Tags: apache-pig

I have a JSON data in the below format

```
{"fname":"peter","lname":"parker","reviews":[10,12],"idnum":123456,"gpa":10.5}
```

I am using below code:

```
data = LOAD "my file.json" USING JsonLoader(name:chararray,name:char array,reviews:({(chararray)},{(char array)}),indium:int,gap:float)
dump data;
```

I get only

```
peter,parker
```

Nothing after the last name. Even I use char array for the int and float places and not able to get those data.

Also, if you have any idea how should I store the result data to .csv file using comma separated. Since, I have a large file (>100GB) and I have to split that file with 1 GB each and I run this pig script and do some analysis and then want to write back to csv file, after processing every  1 GB  will append the data in csv, not individual csv for 100 GB of data in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

PIG JsonLoader does not work properly with json arrays. Better use elephant-bird json libraries. They are quite elegant and easy to use :-

https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/

Regarding your CSV format query I am assuming you know how to parse json and convert it into comma separated string and your question is more about how to split them in 1GB file outputs. If that is the case use parallel property of reducer. Once your are done with json analyzing and parsing using DISTINCT query to have desired output (except in few rare occasions) :-

```
B = DISTINCT A parallel 100;
```

Comment: In case you want to check how to parse JSON :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685850/how-to-process-a-flat-file-with-json-string-as-a-part-of-each-line-into-csv-fil/38686179#38686179